# Int overload for IEnumerable.Select not working (used for row count)

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq expression:

```
    IQueryable posicion = 
       MonthlySales.Where(x => x.StoreCode == 7 && x.Year == 2013 && x.Month== 6)
                   .OrderBy (x=>x.AmountSold )
                   .Select ((f, index )=> new { f.AmountSold, f.ArticleCode, index} )
                   .Take(100);
```

in the select I included "index" to ba able to get the row number

I get a `NotSupportedException`: saying that I used an overload not compatible with the select operator.

the MSDN documentation says that select does have an overload 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx

what could be the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if linq-to-entity accepts that overload

Comment: Even if you get it to work, please note that you're not getting the row number from the database with index, rather the position of each element as it appears in your ordered list after the Where and OrderBy.

Comment: @Davio yes that was my intention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to execute the query against the provider to be able to use that overload

```
   var posicion = 
   MonthlySales.Where(x => x.StoreCode == 7 && x.Year == 2013 && x.Month== 6)
               .OrderBy (x=>x.AmountSold )
               .Take(100);              
               .ToList()
               .Select ((f, index )=> new { f.AmountSold, f.ArticleCode, index} )
```

By calling to `.ToList()` you're executing the query against the provider and converting it into an `IEnumerable<T>`. The overload is then supported. Notice too that I've moved the call to `.Take(100)` to ensure that when you execute your limiting the amount return prior to constructing the list.

you can call `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.ToList()` the main point is to execute the query prior to calling the overload of `.Select`